# Available date range by year

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table that holds date

```
ID      Dates
1       2014-01-20
2       2014-01-21
...
100     2014-05-20 
101     2014-06-01  --Missing a few dates
102     2014-06-02
...
201     2014-10-31
202     2014-12-05  --Missing a few dates
...
349     2015-04-29
350     2015-04-30
```

I want to find the available date range by year between a from and to date, for example

```
@StartDate: 2014/04/06
@EndDate: 2015/04/05
```

The expected result is

```
Year    StartRange      EndRange
2014    2014-04-06      2014-05-20
2014    2014-06-01      2014-10-31
2014    2014-12-05      2014-12-31
2015    2015-01-01      2015-04-05
```

I am trying to find the available date ranges from the Dates column. Lets take the first row in the expected result **2014-04-06 to 2014-05-20** which says I have continuous dates from the 6th April to 20th May then there is a break (I do not have dates from 2014-05-21 to 2014-05-30)

The dates **2014-04-06** (in the first row) and  **2015-04-05** (in the last row) are included in the expected result as it is the start and end date (parameter to the query) and I have those dates in the [Dates] column of my table

Thanks

Comment: This is a vague question. I can't figure out how you get from your input to the expected output...

Comment: I don't understand your expected output. Your inputs are a start and an end date, and your table contains one date. I don't understand what the StartRange and EndRange columns are in your output.

Comment: I am trying to find the available date ranges from the Dates column. Lets take the first row in the expected result 2014-04-06 to 2014-05-20 which says I have continuous dates from the 6th April to 20th May then there is a break (I do not have dates from 2014-05-21 to 2014-05-30)

Comment: what sql server version are you using? with 2012 you can do this in one query with some LAG and LEAD functions. I haven't thought really about alternatives, but in 2008 and downwards you would probably need to write a function or a stored procedure.

Comment: @AaronBertrand 2015-04-05 is value to EndDate (a parameter to the query) so I have to end the sequence, saying that I have data till 2015-04-05

Comment: @Staeff I am using 2008 R2

Comment: @Staeff You need a more complicated query (usually a self-join on a CTE), not explicitly a function or a stored procedure.

Comment: I have added a little more detail If the question is still vague please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an "Islands and Gaps" type of problem.  Here is one way to do it:

```
;
WITH
  cteDays As (SELECT *, DATEDIFF(dd,0,Dates) As DayNo From YourTable)
, cteDifs As 
(
    SELECT *, 
        DayNo-(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Dates, ID)) As Dif
    FROM    cteDays
)
SELECT
    Year(Dates) As [Year],
    MIN(Dates)  As StartRange,
    MAX(Dates)  As EndRange
FROM    cteDifs
GROUP BY Year(Dates), Dif
ORDER BY [Year], StartRange
```